# Writing numerical values on the plot with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible, with Matplotlib, to print the values of each point on the graph?

For example, if I have:

```
x = numpy.range(0,10)
y = numpy.array([5,3,4,2,7,5,4,6,3,2])
pyplot.plot(x,y)
```

How can I display y values on the plot (e.g. print a 5 near the (0,5) point, print a 3 near the (1,3) point, etc.)?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can use the [annotate](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/annotations.html) command to place text annotations at any x and y values you want.  To place them exactly at the data points you could do this

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot

x = numpy.arange(10)
y = numpy.array([5,3,4,2,7,5,4,6,3,2])

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_ylim(0,10)
pyplot.plot(x,y)
for i,j in zip(x,y):
    ax.annotate(str(j),xy=(i,j))

pyplot.show()
```

If you want the annotations offset a little, you could change the `annotate` line to something like

```
ax.annotate(str(j),xy=(i,j+0.5))
```

Comment: +1 Just as a side note, annotate has "offseting the annotations a little" built-in. Just do `ax.annotate(str(j), xy=(i,j), xytext=(10,10), textcoords='offset points')` to offset the annotations by 10 _points_ in the x and y directions.  This is often more useful than offsetting in data coordinates (though that's also an option).

Answer (score 33):

Use `pyplot.text()` (`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[1,2,3]
y=[9,8,7]

plt.plot(x,y)
for a,b in zip(x, y): 
    plt.text(a, b, str(b))
plt.show()
```

Comment: When I use this, it shrinks my graph a lot, do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Current way of displaying values on the bar graph using `plt.text()` would be

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.array([5,3,4,2,7,5,4,6,3,2])
#for modifying figsize
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figisize=(8,12))
ax.bar(x,y)
for i, j in zip(x,y):
    ax.text(i,j, str(j), ha='center', va='bottom')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

hope that helps