# How to get values on line charts

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would to plot corresponding values on line charts. Can you please let me know how can I do that?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3]
y = [3,4,5]
z = [6,7,8]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, z)
plt.show()
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am able to plot correctly. However, I would like to have value on line chart for which I am looking out for a syntax.

Comment: What is the value of a line chart? The x-y line has, for instance, six values, three each for x and y. Which value do you want to add to the chart? Or do you want to add [labels and a legend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#parts-of-a-figure)? I think you should start by reading [the tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html)

Comment: I have gone through the tutorial, but I would like to have y value along the line for the first line and the z value for the second line.

Comment: This has been explained, for instance, here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46063077/8881141

Comment: I have gone through the link, but in my case I have two lines in the same chart. If I follow the same approach it disturb the y axis. Could you please help me to solve above query with code.

Comment: What is the specific code you tried to implement and what does it mean that is "disturbs the y-axis"? Please include the code, the current output, and a description of the difference to the expected output.

Comment: I tried but still it doesn't produce correct output. In case of y axis although both values are more or less similar but it produce lines which are far apart from each other. I request if you could help to code above so that I can see if it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can add value tag to the point by using a `for` loop over the data points in cartesian coordinate.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3]
y = [3,4,5]
z = [6,7,8]

plt.plot(x, y, '*--')
for a,b in zip(x, y): 
    plt.text(a, b, str(b),fontsize=20)
plt.plot(x, z, '*--')
for a,b in zip(x, z): 
    plt.text(a, b, str(b),fontsize=20)

plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.show()
```

[image]