# How to annonate / display y values on plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How can I display the data(y axis values) on the matlotlib graph? 
I found this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282058/writing-numerical-values-on-the-plot-with-matplotlib), I tried suggested solution but it doesn't work here, at least I couldn't figure it out. I'd appreciate if you can help. thanks.

What I try to do here is to plot the y values (mean,aver,dist) against time in three different plots.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from matplotlib import pyplot

conn = mysql.connector.MySQLConnection(user='root', password='', host='127.0.0.1', database='DB')
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql = "SELECT Time, mean, Aver, Dist FROM datatb order by Time Desc limit 100"
cursor.execute(sql)
result = cursor.fetchall()

df = pd.DataFrame(list(result),columns=["Time","Mean","Aver","Dist"])


plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(15, 12), dpi=150, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.title('Mean')
plt.plot(df['Time'], df["Mean"],'o-', c='blue',label=r'$Mean$')
plt.legend(loc='best')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.invert_xaxis()

plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(15, 12), dpi=150, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.title('Aver')
plt.plot(df['Time'], df["Aver"],'o-', c='green', label=r'$Aver$')
plt.legend(loc='best')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.invert_xaxis()

plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(15, 12), dpi=150, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.title('Dist')
plt.plot(df['Time'], df["Dist"], 'o-', c='brown', label=r'$Dist$')
plt.legend(loc='best')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.invert_xaxis()


conn.close()
cursor.close()
```

My plot looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure, what your question is - your subplots seem to be ... unusual. [Maybe this is your aim?](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/shared_axis_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-shared-axis-demo-py)

Comment: Where is the part of the code where you tried the linked solution? In what way did it not work?

Comment: can you add the data ?

Comment: What I try to do is to display the y-values on the line dots.

Comment: I tried this part, `for i,j in zip(x,y):
    ax.annotate(str(j),xy=(i,j))` but I did't know how to implement it exactly, and it didn't work either.

Comment: check this https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `annotate`:

---

**Example:**

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot

x = numpy.arange(10)
y = numpy.array([5,3,4,2,7,5,4,6,3,2])

fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_ylim(0,10)
pyplot.plot(x,y)
for i,j in zip(x,y):
    ax.annotate(str(j),xy=(i,j))

pyplot.show()
```

---

Now, just replace `x` and `y` with `df['Time']` and `df["Mean"]`.

[image]

Comment: yes, but I already gave the link to this solution. This is the solution I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Can you show me how you'd implement this solution to my code? please

Comment: can you add some data? without the data I cannot solve your original problem. I posted this example because you have not posted your data

Comment: I didn't change x and y, when I changed them, it works now. thank you.