# Plot lines to x and y values of maximum in graph with spline interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, max

I'd like to plot a graph and highlight its local maximum by drawing a dotted line back to x and y axis, and displaying the values of both.

For example some data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

x_ = np.array([1, 2.5, 2.7, 8, 3])
y_ = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
spline = make_interp_spline(x_, y_)
x = np.linspace(x_.min(), x_.max(), 500)
y = spline(x)

xmax = x[np.argmax(y)]
ymax = y.max()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(xmax,ymax,'o')
plt.show()
```

How do I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code doesn't really run...

Comment: Aside from the syntax errors I fixed, there are many issues, `x` should be sorted, and `y` should be of the same size

Comment: `.hlines` and `.vlines` will allow you to plot horizontal and vertical lines to a specific location.

Comment: @Reti43, partly yes, but how do I then display the numerical value of my x and y values for the local maximum?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282058/writing-numerical-values-on-the-plot-with-matplotlib). Welcome to the site and please take this as constructive criticism. A search is valuable and can save time. A question that seeks to combine independent things that have been asked before is of little value, unless the combination itself poses a new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general code is OK, but there are two major mistakes:

1- `x` should be sorted

2- `x` and `y` should be of same size

Working version of the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

x_ = np.array([1, 2.5, 2.7, 3, 8])
y_ = np.array([1, 2, 3, 5, 4])
spline = make_interp_spline(sorted(x_), y_)
x = np.linspace(x_.min(), x_.max(), 500)
y = spline(x)

xmax = x[np.argmax(y)]
ymax = y.max()
plt.plot(x_, y_, 'o')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(xmax,ymax,'s')

# annotations
plt.axhline(ymax, ls=':', c='k')
plt.axvline(xmax, ls=':', c='k')
plt.text(xmax, ymax*0.95, f'({round(xmax,2)}, {round(ymax,2)})')

plt.show()
```

[image: spline interpolation]

Comment: The question asks to plot a line from the local maximum to the x and y axes, not to superimpose the original data points on the spline.

Comment: @Reti43 added, but the major issue was the fully broken code